# Why doesn't yarn updated when running upgrade?

Tags: macos, homebrew, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use latest yarn version after upgrading it.
I've follow over https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#mac-stable instructions, but yarn didn't really upgraded.
After running `brew upgrade yarn`:

```
$ brew upgrade yarn
Updating Homebrew...
Error: yarn 1.9.4 already installed
```

And after running `yarn --version`:

```
$ yarn --version
1.9.2
```

Is there any way to use the latest version?
Although the guide says that `brew upgrade yarn` should do it automatically..

Comment: For what it's worth, running just `brew upgrade yarn` worked for me. I suspect this issue has been fixed since it was reported.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a [lengthy thread on Github](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1139) regarding upgrades; here's what is suggested for HomeBrew:

```
brew upgrade yarn
brew link --overwrite yarn
```

Then try `yarn -v`

---

*If that fails then you could:*

First, uninstall brew's yarn:

```
brew uninstall yarn
```

Removing yarn binaries manually:

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
rm -f /usr/local/bin/yarn
```

Remove yarn cache:

```
rm -rf ${HOME}/.yarn
```

If you have the following in your .zshrc or .bash_profile, remove it:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"
```

Install via curl:

```
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

Make sure there is the following line in your .zshrc or .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH"
```

↳ [Github : yarn update discussion thread](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1139)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed yarn with npm in an nvm environment then you can just run `npm -g upgrade yarn`. To check that run `which yarn` -- if you see `.nvm` in the result of that, you are in an nvm environment.